# Mysql index on condition "field IS NULL"

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table with a field "deleted_at" which is a DATETIME, and I would like this kind of requests to be executed quickly:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE deleted_at IS NULL
```

Is it possible to index the "nullness" of the field instead of indexing every single datetime value of my field?

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index) will answer your question.

Comment: yes possible.you can did it.

Comment: Have a look at this link - Partial index : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_index

Answer (score 3):

You can [index nullable columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/is-null-optimization.html), however the index will only be used if  there is good selectivity on the nulls, i.e. only a small percentage of your data is actually null.

Unfortunately, [MySql doesn't support](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43/how-to-create-a-conditional-index-on-mysql) [filtered / partial indexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_index) like `SqlServer`, which allow you to index JUST for rows which are NULL (or NOT NULL).

So TL;DR, if NULLs in `deleted_at` are the exception, not the rule, then create an index, but this will also index the non-null datetime values as well.